# exec async / await won't show coverage in istanbul

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, istanbul

I am using the `execa.shell` promise to run a child process and for some reason nothing after the call is being covered even though it's running.

```
const getCode = async ({cmd, workingDir, stdio}) => {
  try {
    const commandResponse = await execa.shell(cmd, {cwd: workingDir, stdio})
    return commandResponse.code
  } catch (e) {
    return e.code
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: When does the `execa.shell()` promise resolve?  When the program finishes?

Comment: Yeah, should resolve when the child process is finished.

Comment: I wasn't awaiting the containing function.